# An analytic function on an open connected set $|f(1/n)|<2^{-n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be a connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $0$ and let $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ be an analytic map satisfying $$|f(\frac{1}{n})|<\frac{1}{2^n}$$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Then  $f=0$.

I wanted to make a prove by contradiction, so assume $f\neq 0$. Then $f$ is not constant, since $f(z)\to 0$ as $z\to 0$. Choose $k\in\mathbb{N},k>1$ minimal such that $a_k\neq 0$. Then $f(z)=a_k z^k g(z)$ with $g$ analytic satisfying $g(0)=1$. Then there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $|g(z)-1|<\frac{1}{2}$ if $|z|<\epsilon$, then $|f(\frac{1}{n})|=|a_kn^{-k}g(\frac{1}{n})|\leq\frac{1}{2^n}$. I want to find a contradiction for large $n$, but I don't see how I can go on. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Show that $f(0)=0$.

Deduce from here that, if $f \neq 0$ as you assumed, then $f(x)=x^mg(x)$ for some positive integer $m$ and some analytic function $g$ which satisfies $g(0) \neq 0$.

Use the given relation to show that $g(0)=0$.

Comment: Could I also use that I can find $\epsilon>0$ such that $|g(z)|>\frac{1}{2}$ for $|z|<\epsilon$, then conclude that $\frac{1}{2^n}>|f(\frac{1}{n})|>|n^{-k}\frac{a_k}{2}|$ for $n$ larger than $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, which is a contradiction for possibly larger $n$>

Comment: @Johnduck Why is $|g(z)|>\frac{1}{2}$ for $|z| <\epsilon$?

Comment: By my definition, $g(0)=1$, hence continuity implies that $g$ is close to 1 for very small $z$.

Comment: @Johnduck yes, it works.

Comment: How do I show $f(0)=0$?

Comment: @Johnduck Since $f$ is analitic, it is continuous, and hence $$f(0)=\lim_n f(\frac{1}{n})$$

Comment: How would you prove that $g(0)=0?$

Comment: @Johnduck  $$|a_kn^{-k}g(\frac{1}{n})|\leq\frac{1}{2^n} \Rightarrow |g(\frac{1}{n})|\leq\frac{n^k}{a_k2^n}|$$ Now, use $g(0)=\lim_n g(\frac{1}{n})$